# Converting Django model data to variables usable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am new to programming and to SO. I have a question about developing with Django / Python.
I am trying to use django variables into a javascript script.

My model is like this:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lat = models.FloatField(default=0)
    lng = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I am creating a Django app that sends the businesses data to a template

```
def index(request):
    business_list = Business.objects.all()
    context = {'business_list': business_list}
    return render(request, 'kitemap/index.html', context)
```

I would like to transform the list of django objects into a list of objects usable in javascript but i can't manage to do so...i tried the code below but did not work. Could you please help? Thanks

```
    for (var i = 0; i < {{ business_list|length }}; i++) {

        var school = [];

        business[0] = {{ business_list.i.lat }};
        business[1] = {{ business_list.i.lng }};
        business[2] = {{ business_list.i.business_name }}M

        businesses[i] = business;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could serialize the queryset into json format,

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

business = Business.objects.all()
data = json.loads(serializers.serialize("json", business))
#return JsonResponse(json)
context = dict(data=data)
return render(request, 'kitemap/index.html', context)
```

Then you can do the iteration, because, the queryset is converted into list of dicts.

You may need to do something like this,

```
var school = [];
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var business = {};

    business['business_name'] = json[i].fields.business_name;
    business['lat'] = data[i].fields.lat;
    business['lng'] = data[i].fields.lng;
    school.push(business);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am going to try. Does "return JsonResponse(json)" pass data to my index.html template?

Comment: JsonResponse will just return the data in json format, that's my mistake, ignore it.

Comment: Fazil, i have the json string but it can't be used, trying to parse it using _var json_parsed = JSON.parse(json)_ but apparently ynot working..any idea on this? many thanks

Comment: _local variable 'json' referenced before assignment_ on line _ json = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', business_list)) _...

Comment: thankd man. in my template i can't manage to use that data however. if only insert _{{ data }}_ in my template, i see printed the whole dataset. if I try to access data in this way _data[0].fields.lat_ i see nothing. sorry for bothering but i am going crazy, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try also using `safe` template tag in your javascript. You should apply it on a context variable coming from HttpResponse.

Comment: Thanks Kostas. However in my template i can't manage to use that data. As I commented to @fazil, if I only insert {{ data }} in my template, i see printed the whole dataset. If I try to access data in this way _data[0].fields.lat_ i see nothing...